# Adding gaps into dynamic array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the =Filter() function to produce a dynamic array that I am referencing in another cell. Where the output is of the format: [example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjV6q.png)

However, I'd like to return the array in the format: [example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA7Ki.png) with a gap before each record where the "type" changes.

I've tried using a helper column and using an IF statement to enter a blank if the previous record had a different value in column A, and then concatenating the cell reference using the =COUNTBLANK() function to refer to correct record. However, this resulted in a different number of blank rows depending on the order of column A.

Is there a better way of achieving this result?

Thanks,
-L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First put this User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function separate(rng As Range)
    Dim arr
    arr = rng
    Dim U As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim L As Long
    arr = rng
    U = UBound(arr, 1)
    L = LBound(arr, 1)
    
    ReDim arrbig(1 To U * 2, 1 To 2)
    
    j = 2
    arrbig(1, 1) = arr(1, 1)
    arrbig(1, 2) = arr(1, 2)
    
    For i = 2 To U
        If arr(i, 1) <> arr(i - 1, 1) Then
            arrbig(j, 1) = ""
            arrbig(j, 2) = ""
            j = j + 1
        End If
        arrbig(j, 1) = arr(i, 1)
        arrbig(j, 2) = arr(i, 2)
        j = j + 1
    Next i
    j = j - 1
    
    ReDim temp(1 To j, 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To j
        temp(i, 1) = arrbig(i, 1)
        temp(i, 2) = arrbig(i, 2)
    Next i
    
    separate = temp
End Function
```

If we start with raw data in cols **A** and **B** like:

[image]

We create a **dynamic array** in cols **D** and **E** by putting:

```
=FILTER(A1:B15,(A1:A15<>"junk")*(A1:A15<>"Peaches"),"X")
```

in **D1**:

[image]

We create the **formatted** array in cols **G** and **H** by putting this formula in **G1**:

```
=separate(D1#)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in getting back on this. I've just got around to implementing this solution today, and it works perfectly. However there is one small problem. The array in my example was a simplified version of the real thing. In reality I have two different arrays on which I would like to use this function. One of which has 8 columns, the other has 9 columns. I'm not sure how to tweak your formula to get all 8/9 columns to appear in the final dynamic array.

Comment: @LukeBradley  I am not sure.